# "Invalid password" error when using Access Database Engine 2010?

Tags: .net, ms-access, vb6

My client is reporting that my app is installed on one machine pointing to an `ACCDB` file on a server location and everything works fine.

When the app is installed on a second machine pointing to the same `ACCDB` file the app generates the following error:

> Not a valid password

What could be cause of this inconsistency?  The client has told me that all machines are running `XP 32-bit`.

Post number 2 here is essentially the same as what I am experiencing: http://www.accessforums.net/programming/excel-access-adodb-connection-not-valid-password-24373.html

Comment: Please update your question to give more details about your app (front-end). Is it an Access .accdb? Access .accde? Something else? If something else, please state the data access method you used and show your connection string. Also state explicitly whether the back-end .accdb is encrypted.

Comment: The .accdb is accessed by both .NET and VB6 front-end app.  The data access method used is `db.OpenDatabase` in VB6.

Comment: Okay, so you've got two different front-ends. Any details on whether the issue is specific to one of them? Or is it that the first person who connects is okay, but the second one in gets an error? Is the back-end database actually encrypted? Please **edit your question** with these details so people don't have to dredge through the comments to find out what's actually going on.