# What Jet provider is installed with MS Office 2003?

Tags: ms-access, office-2003, ms-jet-ace

I am having problems with an app that uses the `Access Database Engine 2010` on machines where `Office 2003` is installed.  I am getting a "not a valid password" when trying to programmatically access an `ACCDB` file.

What could be the problem?  I am guessing it is a conflict between the `JET` providers of `Office 2003` and the `Access Database Engine 2010`.

What `JET provider` is installed with `Office 2003`?

Comment: re: Your specific "Jet version" question here, see my answer below. re: Your "not a valid password" issue, please follow-up on your earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631582/invalid-password-error-when-using-access-database-engine-2010).

Answer (score 0):

> Access 2000, Access 2002 and Office Access 2003 create a Microsoft Jet 4.0 format database file.

ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303528

I suspect that the actual version of the Jet 4.0 *provider* files (DLLs, etc.) would depend more on the OS + Service_Pack and Updates since Jet is a core Windows component (i.e., it is included in a vanilla Windows install).